# Javascript generate matrix from two object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to convert an infinite number of object arrays into a matrix.

```
height: [1,3,4,5,6,7]
weight: [23,30,40,50,90,100]
```

into

```
1 23
1 30
1 40
1 50
...
3 23
3 30
3 40
...
```

Basically map out all possible combination into a matrix

I tried solving the problem using a few functions in underscore.js

```
                var firstOption = _.first( productOptionKeys );
                $.each( productOptions[ firstOption ].split(","), function(index, value){
                    var matrixRow = [];
                    var matricableOptionKeys = _.reject( productOptionKeys, function(option){ return (option == firstOption); }  );

                    matrixRow.push( value );

                    $.each( matricableOptionKeys, function( index, value ){
                        var matricableOptions = productOptions[ value ].split(",");
                        var matricIndex = 0;
                        for( i=0 ; i<matricableOptions.length; i++ ){
                            matrixRow.push( matricableOptions[ matricIndex ] );
                        }

                        //matricIndex ++;
//                      $.each( productOptions[ value ].split(","), function(index, value){
//                          matrixRow.push( value );
//                          return false;
//                      });
                    });

                    console.log( matrixRow );
                });
```

The object is slightly more complicated in my case since I have to split the string values entered into array. But to ease coming up with solution I omitted that the values are comma separated strings

This is not a duplicate of other similar questions, cause am trying obtain all permutations of an object like on below

```
Object { Height: "23,45,190,800", Width: "11",14",15",20"", Color: "Red,Green,Blue" }
```

the existing solutions only find permutations for arrays, not an object. the values of each key will always be comma separated, so object[ key ].split(",") will return values as array.

If it were possible to concatenate arguments to call function I could make use of one of the existing functions.

Comment: You have to show an attempt, you shouldn't just ask for others to write the code for you

Comment: where is the code you have tried?

Comment: "*Trying to convert an **infinite** number of object arrays*". If it's infinite, I'm afraid you won't be able to do it in a finite time.

Comment: @Oriol not exactly infinite, I guess I was trying to communicate that one would specify more dimensions

Comment: @JuanMendes didn't think it was necessary to show my attempt. But understand, this is not a code for me forum

Comment: @iswak It helps to understand what part you're having difficulty with so someone can help you understand what you are doing wrong. And yes, it also helps to weed out some "code for me" questions

Answer (score 6):

Sure thing, you could use a double for:

```
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<height.length; i++)
    for(var j=0; j<weight.length; j++)
        result.push({ height: height[i], weight: weight[j]});
```

The array called `result` at the end will contain all the possible combinations of `height` and `weight`.

Another way it would be you use the `forEach` method of array:

```
var result = [];
height.forEach(function(h){
    weight.forEach(function(w){
         result.push({ height: h, weight: w});    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var height = [1,3,4,5,6,7];
var weight = [23,30,40,50,90,100];
var res = [];

for(h = 0; h < height.length; h++) {
  for(w = 0; w < weight.length; w++) {
    res.push({h: height[h], w: weight[w]});
  }
}
```